# Positive definite function zoo

Tags: representation-theory, big-list, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

A positive definite function $\varphi: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on a group $G$ is a function that arises as a coefficient of a unitary representation of $G$.

For a definition and discussion of positive definite function see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function).

I've often wished I had a collection of diverse examples of positive definite functions on groups, for the purpose of testing various conjectures. I hope the diverse experience of the participants of this forum can help me collect a list of such examples.

To clarify what I'd like to see:

What is an example of a positive definite function on a group $G$ that is not easily seen to be a coefficient of a unitary representation of $G$? What are some positive definite functions that arise in contexts sufficiently removed from studying the coefficients of unitary representations?

Also, the weirder the group $G$ the better.

**Edit:** There is now a [version of this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73417/) on MO.

Comment: As per request, I've made the question CW.

Comment: I guess my favourite example is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. But it's not quite clear what exactly you're looking for: explicit positive elements of the Fourier algebra or would a function of the form $f \ast \tilde{f}$ for $f \in L^2(G)$ already be satisfactory for you? I find the exposition on positive definite functions in appendix C of [Bekka-de la Harpe-Valette](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf) quite nice, but sect 13.4 and the following chapters of Dixmier's book on $C^\ast$-algebras is still the best source in my opinion (few explicit examples, though).

Comment: let me clarify, Theo.